# how to remove duplicate record from file using shell script:

Tags: shell

I want to remove duplicate line items from my file:

**myfile.txt**

```
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/11/2017
productItem2 ProductName12,ProdutctPrice99,ProductModelHP12,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc2,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice87,ProductModelHP13,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/12/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/11/2017
```

As per above example, I want to eliminate duplicate records - in this case **productItem1** has duplicate. I want to remove duplicated based on these field (**ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11**).

I would like to keep the record which is having recent date. In this example 10/02/2017 is greate but it has two entries - I would like to pick one of them out that two entries.

How can we eliminate in shell script
**Output should be: newFile.txt**

```
productItem2 ProductName12,ProdutctPrice99,ProductModelHP12,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc2,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice87,ProductModelHP13,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/12/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sort myfile.txt|uniq > newFile.txt
```

Comment: This is still giving me duplicate. I'm getting two values: productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,ProductDescription-abc1,09/02/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,ProductDescription-abc1,10/02/2017. I need only one which is having greater date

Answer (score 0):

give this line a try:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0}END{for(x in a) print a[x]}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @Kent - I tried your code but its not printing the duplicate item which has greater date. I edited my post. productItem1 has date 01/11/2017 and 01/12/2017. But I'm seeing in output which has date 01/11/2017 instead of 01/12/2017. Are we missing something here

Answer (score 0):

Short GNU **`datamash`** solution:

```
datamash -st, -g1,2,3 last 5 <file.txt > result.txt
```

The final `result.txt` contents:

```
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/02/2017
productItem2 ProductName12,ProdutctPrice99,ProductModelHP12,09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice87,ProductModelHP13,09/02/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @jprism, just need to add the '-u' (--unique) option  like so:

```
    sort input.file | uniq -u > output.file
```

Comment: If all lines are duplicated, you get no ouput.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
awk -F ' |,' '{t=$NF;gsub("/","",t);if(b[$1]<t){a[$1]=$0;b[$1]=t}}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' infile
```

space or , are fields separator.

Take the last field in t, remove the / to get a number and keep it in array b if it is greater than previous b[$1].

At the same time, array a keep the complete line a[$0].

At the end print array a

Answer (score 0):

Print line with HP12 and the next two following lines.

```
awk '/HP12/{x=NR+2}(NR<=x){print}' file

productItem2 ProductName12,ProdutctPrice99,ProductModelHP12,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc2,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem3 ProductName13,ProdutctPrice87,ProductModelHP13,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc3,,,,,,09/02/2017
productItem1 ProductName11,ProdutctPrice27,ProductModelHP11,10/06/2016,ProductDescription-abc1,,,,,,01/12/2017
```